# I'm creating a CalendarView, but it takes the previous month instead of the current month?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm creating a CalendarView, but it takes the previous month instead of the current month.
Help me !

```
    <CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioGup" />
```

calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener
{ view, year, month, dayOfMonth ->

date = dayOfMonth.toString() + "-" + month.toString() + "-" +year.toString()
Toast.makeText(activity,date,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
adapter(date)
}

**says month = 1**

Comment: How have you implemented it? Please show the code

Comment: no, i dont, all kotlin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/**
         * Called upon change of the selected day.
         *
         * @param view The view associated with this listener.
         * @param year The year that was set.
         * @param month The month that was set [0-11].
         * @param dayOfMonth The day of the month that was set.
         */
        void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth);
```

this will return month value from 0 to 11 ie. 0 for January 11 for December.
So we have to add 1 in month value

Comment: Well if the moon = 11 and we add 1, can't it be 12?

Comment: Since we consider January as the First month & November as the 11th month. So definitely December will be the 12th month. Now This CalendarView returns month value from 0 to 11 range. So to get the actual month value, we have to add 1.